# Padding inside a div

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and CSS and have created a birthday card which I want to have a 50/50 split down the centre  . I have inserted my image on the left however when I add text to the right and side it is too close to the centre line, so I have used some padding (padding-left: 50px;) to move it further across. The issue is when I do this the box on the right increases. I want the box on the right to remain the same size but just be able to adjust the text inside that box without it resizing.

```css
.card {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;    
    border: 5px solid;
    display: flex;

}


.left {
    flex: 1;   
    background-image: url("https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/golden-retriever-royalty-free-image-506756303-1560962726.jpg");
    border-style: solid;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 60% 5%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 600px;
}


.right {
    
    flex: 1;    
    background-color: burlywood;
    border: 5px solid;
    padding-left: 50px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Flex</title>
</head>
    <body>
        
            <div class="card">
            <div class="left">

            </div>
                <div class="right">
                    <h1 class="title">Hello</h1>
                    <h2 class="birthday">Happy Birthday</h2>
                    <p class="message">We really miss you and are thinking about you</p>
                    <p class="bye"> Lots of love and see you soon x</p>
                </div>
            </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `box-sizing: border-box;` to *include*  padding and borders in your width/heigth settings/calculations.

Comment: The short explanation of that is: the default (`content-box`) means the total width of your `<div>` is width+padding+border. `border-box` means the total width is width-(padding+border).

Comment: I have used box-sizing: border-box; in the div class 'card' I also tried

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
} 

at the top of the CSS however when I add padding-left: to the right box the box still gets bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 .card {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;    
    border: 5px solid;
    display: flex;
}


.left {
    background-image: url("https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/golden-retriever-royalty-free-image-506756303-1560962726.jpg");
    border-style: solid;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 60% 5%;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 600px;
}


.right {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: burlywood;
    border: 5px solid;
    padding: 0 25px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sachin, I see that you have removed flex: 1 which I was using as I thought that the was the best way to have 2 divs beside each other at equal spacing. But it looks like using flex 1 and adding padding does not equally space them but if you use 50% width then it does.